# How to get location from OpenWeatherMap API (Current Weather API), pass the data and compare to One Call API?

Tags: flutter, dart, weather, openweathermap, weather-api

Now I'm working on Weather App (https://github.com/Arkadiusz4/Weather-App/tree/master/lib). For this project I use **OpenWeatherMap API**. I've already made a current weather using **Current Weather API**.

In **Current Weather API** there are information about city you search (you search cities in Search Bar) like name of city, latitude and longitude.

I want to expand app to have an hourly and weekly weather forecast. I want to use **One Call API**. There is a problem, that in this API are only information about latitude and longitude, but
there's no name of city.

How I can get information from **Current Weather API** and write to some variables and then "rewrite" this variables to get data from **One Call API** for the same city?

I tried to equal some variables like this:

```
_responseCurrent?.coordinates.lat == _responseOnecall?.lat;
_responseCurrent?.coordinates.long == _responseOnecall?.long;
```

but there is error from **One Call API** (statusCode == 200) there's no city like this.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but, to help you debug, just `console.log(_responseOneCall)` to the browser and you'll see all of the properties in the Debug Console.

Comment: Ok, I will try.